# How to check if a specific key is in a dictionary using parameters of a new function?

Tags: python

So i have a dictionary:

```
dict = {
  "Rainbows" : {"yay":[1,1,1], "teehee":[2, 87, 7], "yaw":[7, 2.5, 2.9], "foo":[7, 5, 14.5], "bar":[20.2, 22, 14.5] } , 
  "Rain" : {"yay":[1,1,1], "teehee":[1.232, 1.778, 5.66], "yaw":[], "foo":[20, 61.0], "bar":[8.0, 28.0, 118.0] }
}
```

From that, I need to create a function that creates a new dictionary based on the **key** (ie. "Rainbows", "Rain") that computes things like average and max, min.

```
{
  "yay" : [mean, min, max],
  "teegee" : [mean, min, max],
  "yaw" : [mean, min, max],
  "foo" : [mean, min, max],
  "bar" : [mean, min, max]
}
```

I have

```
def random_data(dictionary, key):

    rainbow = {}

    if key in dictionary:

        rainbow[key] = {
            "yay": [],
            "teehee": [],
            "yaw": [],
            "foo": [],
            "bar": []
        }
```

where **dictionary** is an input of a dictionary (ie. "dict") and where **key** is an input of a key. So it could be "Rainbows" (which exists in the original dict) or "Table" (which doesn't exist in the original dict)
How do I make sure that I check that the **key**("Rainbows" , "Rain") is inside of the dictionary input (ie. dict) i am given, in order to proceed with making the new dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use following function snippet if I am understanding your question correctly:

```
def random_data(dictionary, key):
    ans = dict()

    if key in dictionary:
        for k in dictionary[key]:
            ans[k] = dictionary[key][k]

    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

One important thing. Don't override built in variables e.g dict, str, int. Try to use get() method. e.g  dic.get(key, False).